# Google Analytics Site Search Tracking on Mobile Site

Tags: mobile, google-analytics

we are trying to track the search on one of our clients mobile site with google analytics site search tracking function but it just doesn't work. We do this by pushing virtual page views. We adjusted the search terms in the tracking code and in the view settings (searchparamter: search). On the normal website the site search tracking works just fine but on the mobile site it just won't function right. Both sites are in one property and only use filters to include/exclude mobile/website traffic. In the reportings of the mobile site search there is only very few data and all of our test keywords were not tracked.

When searching on the mobile site, the URL is output as:
http://de.website.mobi/search.php?search=test

This is the code we use on the mobile site:

```
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-43881360-1');
    ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);

                ga('send', 'pageview'
                                , { 'page': '/search.php?search=test' }
                                        );
```

I'm really thankful for new ideas or general feedback! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to:

- Go to your google analytics admin panel
- Go the view you want to track the site search under. Its the last column to the right
- Click on "View Settings"
- Click on "Site Search Settings" (bottom)
- Turn it on
- Type in search

Save it and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we already did that from the beginning. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Are you sure you are not filtering out traffic from the profile you implemented the instructions above for?

Comment: You wouldn't need to send a pageview manually to get that search. IF the URL changes when someone searches then the above settings should be sufficient enough to make it work.

Comment: We are just filtering the web traffic from the mobile profile to make sure all traffic from the normal website is in the profile for the normal website and that the mobile traffic is in the profile for the mobile site. Thanks for your last answer. We will test it without sending the pageview.

Comment: The URL changes when someone searches and we tested it without sending the pageview but it still won't work. Of all test searches we made, only one was tracked. Do you still have any other idea?